# Angular2 beta , using interface all the time undefined property

Tags: interface, angular

```lavascript
export interface User {
    country_name: string,
    password:     string,
    email:        string,
}

// login.conponent
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {User} from "../../interfaces/user";
import {OnInit} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector:'login',
    templateUrl:'app/components/login/login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    newUser: User;

    constructor() {}

    onSubmit(email = "",password = "") {
       this.newUser.email = email; // as example        
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Any time when i try use newUser it write me undefind, no metter in what side i will call, all the time exeption. Also if try to look on ngInit it also undefind.
What did i can missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined interface for the user

```
export interface UserInterface {
    country_name: string,
    password: string,
    email: string,
}
```

however you still need to create `User` instance if you want to use it.

```
export class App {

    newUser: User;

    constructor() {
        this.newUser = new User();
        this.newUser.email = 'test@asd.com'
    }
}
```

For this make sure `User` class implements `UserInterface`:

```
export class User implements UserInterface {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this.newUser` is not defined.

You need to initialize it before assigning any property values, eg. something like:

`this.newUser = { country_name: null, password: null, email: null}`